# Simplifying query across multiple columns

Tags: sql, select

I have a table of classroom names that I want to compare against several known instruments.  My table has a total of 11 columns but four of the columns contain the section leader instrument names(instrument1...instrument4).  I want to create a SQL statement that will compare the two instruments I am looking for against the four names present in each column per row.

**ex.  I need to find Trumpet and trombone**

I would think it would look something like this.

**Here is the statement that I have**

```
SELECT *
FROM   section_info
WHERE  ( instrument1 = trombone
          OR instrument2 = trombone
          OR instrument3 = trombone
          OR instrument4 = trombone )
       AND ( instrument1 = trumpet
              OR intsrument2 = trumpet
              OR instrument3 = trumpet
              OR instrument4 = trumpet )
```

**Is there a way to simplify?**

Comment: Normalise your database design.

Comment: I agree with Niel. If you change your DB design to have a join table, you will be much happier with your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your database structure, this code is just fine. Just make sure you [format it nicely](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) and spell [trombone](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3a%20trombone&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) correctly.

You always have the option of adjusting your database structure, however.

You could:

1. Create a `Player` table, which has fields `PlayerID` and `PlayerName`.
2. Create an `Instruments` table, which has fields `InstrumentID` and `InstrumentName`.
3. Finally, create a `Player_Instruments` table, which has fields `PlayerID` and `InstrumentID`. This maps Instruments to Players.

**Select Players who own a trumpet OR trombone:**

```
SELECT *
FROM   players AS P
       INNER JOIN player_instruments AS PI ON PI.PlayerID = P.PlayerID 
       INNER JOIN instruments AS I ON I.InstrumentID = PI.InstrumentID
WHERE  I.InstrumentName = 'trumpet'
        OR I.InstrumentName = 'trombone'
```

**Select Players who own a trumpet and trombone:**

```
SELECT *
FROM   players AS P
       INNER JOIN player_instruments AS TRUMP ON TRUMP.playerid = P.playerid
       INNER JOIN instruments AS TRUMP_I ON TRUMP_I.instrumentid = TRUMP.instrumentid AND TRUMP_I.InstrumentName = 'trumpet'
       INNER JOIN player_instruments AS TROM ON TROM.playerid = P.playerid
       INNER JOIN instruments AS TROM_I ON TROM_I.instrumentid = TROM.instrumentid AND TROM_I.InstrumentName = 'trombone'
```

The [Inner Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) here causes only those players who have a valid mapping to a trumpet and trombone be included in the result set.

Comment: Not to mention "instrument", and dare I say it, "spell".

Comment: haha... whoops. I suppose you could smell the trombone correctly, right?

Comment: *smell trombone correctly* - more specifically, start at the mouthpiece and savour the aroma; note the hint of acidity and barnyard notes; moving along to the slide, inhale the crisp scent of grease mingled with a brassy overtone; finish at the bell, and enjoy the funky air that only a trombone can emit.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM SECTION_INFO
 WHERE INSTRUMENT1 in ('TROMBONE', 'TRUMPET')
 or INSTRUMENT2 in ('TROMBONE', 'TRUMPET')
 or INSTRUMENT3 in ('TROMBONE', 'TRUMPET')
 or INSTRUMENT4 in ('TROMBONE', 'TRUMPET')
```

Not a lot simpler, but since you are comparing multiple columns, I don't see much alternative.

EDIT: Now that I reread the question, this may not work well if you have to have both a Trombone AND a Trumpet. So I may have failed on this. :) Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following table schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `instruments` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `instrument` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `section_info` (
    `instrument1` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `instrument2` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `instrument3` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `instrument4` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

You could do the following:

```
SELECT si.*, inst_1.instrument, inst_2.instrument, inst_3.instrument, inst_4.instrument      
FROM section_info si                                                                         
    LEFT JOIN instruments as inst_1 ON si.instrument1=inst_1.id                               
    LEFT JOIN instruments as inst_2 ON si.instrument2=inst_2.id                               
    LEFT JOIN instruments as inst_3 ON si.instrument3=inst_3.id                               
    LEFT JOIN instruments as inst_4 ON si.instrument4=inst_4.id                               

WHERE                                                                                        
    # instrument 1 is a trombone...                                                           
    ( si.instrument1 = 1 OR si.instrument2 = 1 OR si.instrument3 = 1 OR si.instrument4 = 1 )  
    AND                                                                                       
    # instrument 2 is a trumpet...                                                            
    ( si.instrument1 = 2 OR si.instrument2 = 2 OR si.instrument3 = 2 OR si.instrument4 = 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to simplify the query script for yourself, then you could rewrite the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE 'trombone' IN (instrument1, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4)
  AND 'trumpet'  IN (instrument1, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4)
```

But I must say, this may prevent the DB engine from using indexes on the said columns, if any.